# Ftp sem cabo usb não funciona

Tags: xamarin, ftp

Estou com um problema a dias e não consigo resolver. Montei uma rotina para ftp no xamarin e a mesma funciona perfeitamente desde que o cabo usb (utilizado para depuração) esteja conectado (note e smart) ou seja se abro o xamarin e faço execução no modo debug a rotina funciona perfeitamente. Se tiro o cabo e executo o aplicativo no celular, a rotina grava um pedaço da imagem mas a mesma não retorna.
Gerei uma release e ela também grava pedaço da imagem e a rotina não retorna.

Alguém saberia dizer o que está acontecendo?

abaixo o código para ftp

```
public void sendAPicture(byte[] picture, int _cdn_stb, string _imb_prt_mnu)
{
    string _cds_stb = _cdn_stb.ToString("0000");        
    string ftpUser = "sasasas";
    string ftpPassword = "sasasas";
    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://www.meusite.com.br/wordpress/imagens/" + _cds_stb + "/" + _imb_prt_mnu; ;

    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpfullpath));

    //userid and password for the ftp server  
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.UsePassive = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    ftp.ContentLength = picture.Length;

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();

    var grava = new Task(() =>
    {
        ftpstream.Write(picture, 0, picture.Length);
    });
    grava.Start();
    grava.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    ftpstream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Não sei até onde isso pode influenciar , mas você não está fazendo o `dispose` do stream. Já tentou encapsular o uso dele dentro de um bloco `using`? O resultado é o mesmo?